# How to evaluate AMCL localization performance

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, performance, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm using amcl for localization in a mobile robot. Now succesfully I have it working on the robot. My idea is to use it with a laser scan and I will be modifying the readings so the information passed to the localization algorithm is somehow filtered.

What I want to do now is to evaluate the performance of one filter vs. the original data, is there any information that amcl output so I can do it?. I think I can use the spread of the particles, but seeing from the execution this doesn't always reflect the accuracy of the localization, as sometimes the variance is small but the robot is not in its right orientation.

Other way to ask the question would be: how can I compare odometry vs. laser base localization using amcl algorithm?

Thanks for your thoughts and ideas,

Ibraim

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42474/how-to-evaluate-amcl-localization-performance/) by [Ibraim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3099/ibraim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you considered using stage simulation? That way you have the ground truth pose (exactly where the robot is in the simulated world) which you can compare against the amcl pose.

For example, you can compare the euclidean distance between the two poses after moving the robot on a fixed path. Run this for both laser inputs, and whichever has the lowest (average!) distance is presumably the better one.

---

Originally posted by [HammyG](https://answers.ros.org/users/4052/hammyg/) with karma: 51 on 2013-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1